# Какие Java технологии сейчас актуальны чтобы устроиться на Junior'a?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Сейчас самостоятельно изучаю Java, поэтому у меня возник вопрос о том, какие Java технологии используются сейчас, а какие уже устарели.

Так же хочу знать, используется ли сейчас Java для разработки desktop приложений или она сейчас вся в web, и, соответственно, можно ли найти вакансию на Desktop-разработчика

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сейчас многие требуют знаний Spring, Hibernate, jQuery, JSON, AJAX, протокол TCP/IP, а так-же устаревший JSP. А вообще полистай вакансии на junior'a, там в принципе будут похожие списки требований.

Answer (score 3):

Вы поймите, у Junior'a не возникнет таких вопросов.
А вообще, программист, сам решает на каком языке зарабатывать.
Высокоуровневый это или низкоуровневый язык, что для себя предпочтете, тем и будете зарабатывать.

Сравнивать языки не надо, просто нужно знать, что каждый язык по своему хорош, есть и плюсы и минусы.

По актуальности явы, да Android за себя скажет. К тому-же ява кросплатформенная и серверная часть, довольно хорошо развита, богатые возможности и можно разрабатывать довольно масштабные проекты.

Comment: Я и не пытался сравнивать языки. Еще раз повторю свой вопрос:
что нужно знать кроме Java Core, синтаксиса языка, коллекций для того, чтобы можно было начать искать работу Java-разработчика.

Comment: @Artem Gafarov, нужно уметь решать задачи, предоставляемые заказчиком в виде т.з.

Comment: @And ну это и ежу понятно, но вот очень часто нельзя или очень сложно решить задачу без использования дополнительных технологий. Поэтому я и хочу знать, что нужно изучать кроме Java Core, и какие библиотеки и технологии сейчас актуальны

Answer (score 3):

Используется ли сейчас Java для разработки desktop приложений - да, конечно используется. но работу найти на такие проекты будет трудновато, вакансий мало. Если посмотрите вакансии то увидите что в основном все на веб, android.
SQL надо знать.
а в остальном Вам надо подумать в какой сфере хотите разрабатывать, и там уже смотрите по параметрам вакансий.